# Python: Method M is a property of Class C; How do I use it inside of C?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance, self

I want to use a basic function (method), inside the same class that its defined in.

I don't know why, but it has to do something with `self`.

**This works:**

```
class What(object):
    def worksOnlyOutside(self, a):
        print a ** 2

    def worksOnlyInside(b):
        print b ** 3

    worksOnlyInside(2)
        #prints out 8

What().worksOnlyOutside(3)
    #prints out 9
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
class What(object):
    def worksOnlyOutside(self, a):
        print a ** 2

    def worksOnlyInside(b):
        print b ** 3

    worksOnlyOutside(2)
        #prints out "TypeError: worksOnlyOutside() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

What().worksOnlyInside(3)
    #prints out "TypeError: worksOnlyInside() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"
```

From that I understand that if I want it as an instance outside the class, I need a parameter `self`. Moreover- to use it internally, I need to skip supplying a `self` as a parameter.

**Bottom line: What do I do if I want a method that can both be used inside its class, and be called as a property of that class outside out it?**

Class `Basic Maths` has a method `squared`. It's likely I'll need it both inside and outside the class, since squaring ints is something you do a lot. There must be another option besides defining two different methods - one with a `self` to be used externally, and one without it to be used internally.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Your worksOnlyOutside code should be the correct one to create class method. To call the method within the class, use self.worksOnlyOutside(2)

Answer (score 0):

If a function is an instance method, its first parameter should be a reference to `self`.

I have to guess in your first example, Python is realizing that you intend the method to be called statically, and not requiring the first parameter to be `self`.

- If you intend the method to be static, don't have a `self` parameter
- If you intend the method to be an instance method, have the first parameter be `self`.